# Deploying Endpoint Addresses in WCF

Tags: wcf

Hello I am a bit confused with endpoints, I have been reading about them for a while now and just cant grasp it. So please forgive my lack of knowledge here.

Lets say i have an endpoint on both client and server.

```
<service name="MyProject.Server.Services.CustomerManager">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5000/CustomerService"
      binding="netTcpBinding" name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="HandHeld.ServerContracts.Contracts.ICustomerService" />
  </service>
```

I have everything working tested and ready to deploy. I need to put the server app on a server that is called SQL. can someone please tell me what to change and why?

Comment: Are you hosting the service in IIS?

Comment: just in a console app.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to use net.tcp://SQL:5000/CustomerService"

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: yes there is some sort of security error